# Google maps creation of geofencing for iOS

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios, geofencing

Does google maps provide the ability to create geofence in iOS?

Similar to this for Android:
http://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing.html

Thank you.

Comment: Provide some code what you done.

Comment: I want to create a geofence in iOS using google maps but I could not find the relevant api

Answer (score 2):

Just in case someone else end up here :

https://www.raywenderlich.com/136165/core-location-geofencing-tutorial

Geofencing notifies your app when its device enters or leaves geographical regions you set up. It lets you make cools that can trigger a notification whenever you leave home, or greet users with the latest and greatest deals whenever favorite shops are nearby. In this geofencing tutorial, you’ll learn how to use region monitoring in iOS with Swift – using the Region Monitoring API in Core Location.[...]

Comment: @return0 thanks , i didn't clarify . Does google maps provide the ability to create geofence in iOS? => NO. So you have to do it with core location

Comment: Ah, ok that makes sense. You should include that in the original answer then.

Answer (score 0):

In swift 5 You can create the geofencing by using the Google Map Object. In the view did load or anywhere in the code where you want to initialize the path just instantiate the GMSMutablePath object

```
 var path : GMSMutablePath!
 //In viewdidload
 path = GMSMutablePath()
 let lat  = Double(i.latitude ?? "0") ?? 0.0
 let lng =  Double(i.longitude ?? "0") ?? 0.0
 print(lat,lng)
 path.add(CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: lat, longitude: lng))
 let polyline = GMSPolyline(path: path)
 polyline.strokeColor = AppColor.authFontColor
 polyline.strokeWidth = 3.0
 polyline.map = googleMapView
```